# Multiple classes that inherit from rclcpp::Node in one executable

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to implement a ROS Node that manages multiple objects which each have their own subscriptions. Now for an object to have its own subscriptions the class needs to inherit from `rclcpp::Node`. So is it possible to have to compile two different classes that both inherit from `rclcpp::Node` in one executable or does this break ROS 2 design rules?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383261/multiple-classes-that-inherit-from-rclcpp::node-in-one-executable/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2021-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you make two different classes that derive from `rclcpp::Node` and create instances of both of them then you will have two different nodes. That is sometimes a valid pattern but it sounds like you probably don't want to do that from your first sentence.

> Now for an object to have its own subscriptions the class needs to inherit from rclcpp::Node

This is not accurate, it only needs to have access to a `Node` object when creating the subscriptions. You could easily create the node object and then pass it to the constructor of these other subscription-holding objects, which would then manage the subscriptions as needed.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2021-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So is it possible to have to compile two different classes that both inherit from rclcpp::Node in one executable or does this break ROS 2 design rules?

You could create each node in separate files and use them in one executable using node composition. Please take a look at this example https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/composition/src/manual_composition.cpp.

You can read more about composition here:

- https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/About-Composition.html
- https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Composition.html
- https://roscon.ros.org/2019/talks/roscon2019_composablenodes.pdf

---

Originally posted by [carlossvg](https://answers.ros.org/users/45899/carlossvg/) with karma: 116 on 2021-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1